# AJAX get returns 404 in Spring

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

help me
**index.jsp**

```
$("#btn-submit").click(function () {
    var username=document.getElementById("username");
    var password=document.getElementById("password");
    $.ajax({
        url:"login",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'text',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: {
            username:username.value,
            password:password.value
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response=="1") {
                alert(response);
            }
            else alert(response);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
});
```

**LoginController.java**

```java
@RequestMapping("/login")
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public int checkValid(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale, Model model){
        try {
            if (userService.findByUserName(username).equals(hashPass(password))){
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public String hashPass(String pass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hashInBytes = md.digest(pass.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // bytes to hex
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**spring-config-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
    
    
    
        
            /WEB-INF/pages/
        
        
            .jsp
        
    
    
        
            /resources/jdbc.properties

```
<!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                      transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type
  DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="postsDAO" class="com.blog.dao.impl.PostsDAO">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="postsService" class="com.blog.service.impl.PostsService">
    <property name="postsDAO" ref="postsDAO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.blog.dao.impl.UserDAO">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userService" class="com.blog.service.impl.UserService">
    <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"/>
</bean>
```

I use tomcat 9
Error:Failed to load resource: the server responded http://localhost:8080/Blog_war_exploded/login?username=root&password=root with a status of 404 ()

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error: You are accessing `http://localhost:8080/Blog_war_exploded/login` but you actually want to access `http://localhost:8080/login`.

The reason is that you specified your URL as `login` instead of `/login`, so it is relative to the current "directory" and not to the root.

Changing the code to use `/login` should fix it:

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login",
        ...
    })
```

*On a side note, it's not a good idea to this via GET requests - among other things, the password will be stored in the server log in clear text. You should use a POST request instead.*

---

**Update:**

Also, it seems you are use *two* request mappings for `/login` on top of each other, so you'll end up with `/login/login`. Check out [how to use `@RequestMapping` properly](https://springframework.guru/spring-requestmapping-annotation/).

Try changing the second (method-level) one to `@RequestMapping(value = { "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)` or just `@RequestMapping("/")`.

Comment: `/login`, not `/ login`. And what does "didn't work" mean? Please share what exactly happened, I'm sure the error message is different.

Comment: After editing I get the error: GET http://localhost:8080/login?username=1&password=1 404
sorry for bad english

Comment: Did you try the second fix as well in my updated answer? Regarding the request mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to your RequestMapping definition on both controller level and method level.

the first login at the controller level, means if you want to access any services in this controller, your requests have to start with "/login"

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
@Controller
public class LoginController {
```

and the second login at the method level, means you want to call the /login service under /login.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public int checkValid(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale, Model model){
```

So the valid URL to call the /login service under /login controller is: /login/login

and because of this, your url /login was not found

you can either remove the first /login at the controller level, or use the /login/login from your ajax request...